# Undo swipe in recycler view on pressing back button?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

How to restore the swiped view on pressing back button in recyclerView ?

MY CODE

RecyclerListAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerListAdapter.ItemViewHolder>
        implements ItemTouchHelperAdapter {


    private final List<Card> mItems = new ArrayList<>();

    Card car1 = new Card(R.drawable.card1, "Text First");
    Card car2 = new Card(R.drawable.card1, "Text Second");
    Card car3 = new Card(R.drawable.card3, "Text First");
    Card car4 = new Card(R.drawable.card4, "Text Second");
    Card car5 = new Card(R.drawable.card3, "Text First");
    Card car6 = new Card(R.drawable.card2, "Text Second");

    public RecyclerListAdapter() {
        mItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(car1, car2,car3,car4,car5,car6));
    }

    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card, parent, false);
        ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(view);
        return itemViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Card card = mItems.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(card.getText());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(card.getImage());

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemDismiss(int position) {

        mItems.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        Card prev = mItems.remove(fromPosition);
        mItems.add(toPosition > fromPosition ? toPosition - 1 : toPosition, prev);
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }


    public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements
            ItemTouchHelperViewHolder {

        public final TextView textView;
        public final ImageView imageView;

        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.heading_text);
            imageView= (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected() {
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClear() {
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(0);
        }
    }
}
```

SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback.java

```
public class SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {

    private final ItemTouchHelperAdapter mAdapter;

    public SimpleItemTouchHelperCallback(ItemTouchHelperAdapter mAdapter) {
        this.mAdapter = mAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled() {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        int dragFlags = 0;
        int swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.END;
        return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, swipeFlags);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        mAdapter.onItemMove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        mAdapter.onItemDismiss(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

    }


    public void onSelectedChange(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionstate) {
        if (actionstate != ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE) {
            ItemTouchHelperViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemTouchHelperViewHolder) viewHolder;
            itemViewHolder.onItemSelected();
        }
        super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionstate);
    }
    @Override
    public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView,RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder){
        super.clearView(recyclerView,viewHolder);

        ItemTouchHelperViewHolder itemViewHolder =  (ItemTouchHelperViewHolder) viewHolder;
        itemViewHolder.onItemClear();
    }
}
```

ItemTouchHelperAdapter.java

```
public interface ItemTouchHelperAdapter {
void onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition);
void onItemDismiss(int position);
}
```

ItemTouchHelperViewHolder.java

```
public interface ItemTouchHelperViewHolder {
 void onItemSelected();
   void onItemClear();

}
```

Everything works fine but i need to know how to get the swiped view back on pressing back button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `OnItemDismiss` method, save a copy of the item you are removing then just create an `OnItemRestore` method that places it back in the adapter.

Call the new method from the `OnBackPressed` method of the Activity

```
private Object lastRemovedItem;
private int lastIndex=-1;

@Override
public void onItemDismiss(int position) {

    lastRemovedItem=mItems.get(position);
    lastindex=position;

    mItems.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public void restoreLastItem(){
   if (lastIndex==-1) return;
   mItems.add(lastindex,lastRemovedItem);
   notifyItemInserted(lastIndex);
   lastRemovedItem=null;
   lastIndex=-1;
}
```

Comment: should i save copy of the item inside onSwiped method ??

Comment: No. I said in the `OnItemDismiss` method. Store the saved item in your adapter class then it is easy to restore fgrom the new method I suggested. See edited answer with example

Comment: Thanks a ton it works however only for the last removed view what if i want the views before that?

Comment: Same way. Save the ones you want when you remove them then restore them when you want them back.

Comment: okay but can i loop it through as it is a cardview and i will disable vertical scroll so one has to swipe in order & my question is can i loop it back as eachtime OnBackPressed is called the swiped view is restored & before that & before that until first .Thanks

Comment: If you have a new question, you can press the "Ask Question" button above. You should not keep adding new questions as comments to your existing ones